# compile opencv2.3.1 in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, undefined-reference

Here is the tutorial I followed:http://thebitbangtheory.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/how-to-install-opencv-2-3-1-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-with-python-support/
I think the problem is ffmpeg, the version I used is 0.8.10, and I installed it in /usr and enabled share, but when I complied opencv,the output was full of

> ./../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `av_codec_get_id'
>   ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to`av_seek_frame'
>   ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `avpicture_get_size

Comment: Those symbols are defined in `/usr/lib/libavcodec.so`.

Comment: Mmn..But I think the Linker couldn't find the libavcodec, what can I do? except export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Remove ffmpeg, and install it through the Ubuntu Software Center. Then, recompile the whole shebang.

Comment: what's your meaning by saying recompile the whole shebang?

Comment: Go back to your tutorial, and follow the instructions to remove ffmpeg from the system. After that, recompile OpenCV.

Comment: @karlphillip Hello,I tried to install ffmepg by apt-get install,but the version I get is 0.7.3,still,I tried to make clean the opencv and recompile it,here is mistakes I get:  /home/pris-server/software/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:103:36: fatal error： libavformat/avformat.h：No such files or directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @karlphillip and @Appleman1234, and I solved my problem finally. The key is remove the /release directory that contains the cmake information and do the recompile from scratch, i.e. mkdir ./release, cd ./release, cmake, make and make install. BTW,ffmpeg is required 0.8+,and mine is 0.8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH, along with the location you installed ffmpeg to.

See [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1077) for more information on the steps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have seen the steps before,but it didn't work for me. The LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH is /usr/lib and /usr/lib/pkgconfig in my computer.