# How to resolve OpenCV 2.3.1 compilation error on Ubuntu 11.10 due to FFmpeg

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [compile opencv2.3.1 in ubuntu 11.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307824/compile-opencv2-3-1-in-ubuntu-11-10)

How do you prepare your environment so you can properly compile OpenCV 2.3.1 on Ubuntu 11.10?

I'm following the OpenCV [install guide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide), but it's instructions are frustratingly complex.

However, I've distilled it into the following script:

```
sudo apt-get install --yes cmake libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev libtiff4 libtiff4-dev libjasper1 libjasper-dev libpng12-0 libpng12-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev openexr zlibc zlib1g zlib1g-dev python2.7-dev libgtk-3-dev gcc g++ libtbb-dev
cd /tmp
wget --output-document=OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.bz2 http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.3.1/OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.bz2/download?use_mirror=iweb
tar -xvjf OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.bz2
cd OpenCV-2.3.1
mkdir release
cd release
time cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
time make
```

Everything runs succesfully, except of course for `make` which exits with the error:

```
/tmp/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1339:41: error: ‘guess_format’ was not declared in this scope
/tmp/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1367:31: error: ‘av_alloc_format_context’ was not declared in this scope
/tmp/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1411:9: warning: ‘int av_set_parameters(AVFormatContext*, AVFormatParameters*)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1363) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1411:35: warning: ‘int av_set_parameters(AVFormatContext*, AVFormatParameters*)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1363) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1415:5: warning: ‘void dump_format(AVFormatContext*, int, const char*, int)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1485) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1415:35: warning: ‘void dump_format(AVFormatContext*, int, const char*, int)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1485) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1442:15: warning: ‘int avcodec_open(AVCodecContext*, AVCodec*)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3650) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1442:36: warning: ‘int avcodec_open(AVCodecContext*, AVCodec*)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3650) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1479:13: warning: ‘int url_fopen(AVIOContext**, const char*, int)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavformat/avio.h:278) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1479:52: warning: ‘int url_fopen(AVIOContext**, const char*, int)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavformat/avio.h:278) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1485:5: warning: ‘int av_write_header(AVFormatContext*)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1421) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1485:25: warning: ‘int av_write_header(AVFormatContext*)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1421) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Yes, it has a very similar name to the other question, but after reading each question's description, the cause of the compilation error is very different. The other question has a problem with highgui, while I have a problem with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't have the good ffmpeg libraries. There is at least two solutions.
If you need ffmpeg, try to install it thanks to :

```
sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
```

If you don't need to use ffmpeg in your openCV applications, you can try to disable it adding :

```
WITH_FFMPEG=OFF WITH_GSTREAMER=OFF
```

to your cmake configuration line.

Cheers,

Comment: As you can see from the script in my question, I've already installed those packages...

Comment: Sorry, but your script is : sudo apt-get install --yes cmake libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev libtiff4 libtiff4-dev libjasper1 libjasper-dev libpng12-0 libpng12-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev openexr zlibc zlib1g zlib1g-dev python2.7-dev libgtk-3-dev gcc g++ libtbb-dev.

I don't see ffmpeg here

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I did install them, but forgot to update my question.